# PolygonCollider2D.Cast() does not detect TilemapCollider2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to stop the character (`PolygonCollider2D`) from moving through a wall (`TilemapCollider2D`).

```cs
1 var hitResults = new RaycastHit2D[10];
2 var hitX = collider.Cast(new Vector2(desiredX, 0), bodyFilter, hitResults);
3 //var test = new Collider2D[10];
4 //hitX = collider.OverlapCollider(bodyFilter, test);
5 if (hitX == 0)
6 {
7     transform.Translate(desiredX, 0, 0);
8 }
```

Why does the character not stop moving horizontally when I run the code like this? I proved the character can collide with the wall because it does stop moving horizontally when I uncomment the two lines (3&4).

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Comment: Ah yes, I was aware of that because I read the text in the tag. I don't know how it got added. Thanks for removing it!

Comment: You added it in your [Edit 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71437233/revisions) ;)

Comment: @derHugo Yeah I saw that, I don't know how I added it in Edit 3

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.Cast.html), `Collider2D.Cast` only works if the gameobject has a `RigidBody2D`. I do not want to use `RigidBody2D` because i'm not using the physics in my game.

I ended up adding a `CapsuleCollider2D` to the gameobject and doing the cast with the `Physics2D.CapsuleCast` method:

```
var capsuleCollider = GetComponentInChildren<CapsuleCollider2D>();

var hitX = Physics2D.CapsuleCast(transform.position, capsuleCollider.size, capsuleCollider.direction, 0, new Vector2(moveDelta.x, 0), Mathf.Abs(desiredX), wallFilter.layerMask);
if (hitX.collider == null)
{
    transform.Translate(desiredX, 0, 0);
}
```

In my opinion, this is a workaround. There must be a way to cast the `PolygonCollider2D`.